# Obtain public key from private SecKeyRef

Tags: c, macos, cryptography, security.framework

Given a `SecKeyRef` loaded using `SecItemImport` from an RSA private key is there a way to obtain or create a `SecKeyRef` for only the public key components? In OpenSSL this could be done by copying the modulus and public exponent to a new struct, but `SecKeyRef` is opaque and I've been unable to find a function that performs this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of macOS 10.12, iOS/tvOS 10, and watchOS 3 the function [SecKeyCopyPublicKey](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1643774-seckeycopypublickey?language=objc) now exists to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but because I was fighting with it today, I found a way. Let's say you have base64 encoded public RSA key (it's not certificate, it's not der, pem, ...), created in Java (X509 certificate public key), you can create `SecKeyRef` in this way:

```
- (NSData *)stripPublicKeyHeader2:(NSData *)keyBits {
  // Skip ASN.1 public key header
  if (keyBits == nil) {
    return nil;
  }

  unsigned int len = [keyBits length];
  if (!len) {
    return nil;
  }

  unsigned char *c_key = (unsigned char *)[keyBits bytes];
  unsigned int  idx    = 0;

  if (c_key[idx++] != 0x30) {
    return nil;
  }

  if (c_key[idx] > 0x80) {
    idx += c_key[idx] - 0x80 + 1;
  }
  else {
    idx++;
  }

  if (idx >= len) {
    return nil;
  }

  if (c_key[idx] != 0x30) {
    return nil;
  }

  idx += 15;

  if (idx >= len - 2) {
    return nil;
  }

  if (c_key[idx++] != 0x03) {
    return nil;
  }

  if (c_key[idx] > 0x80) {
    idx += c_key[idx] - 0x80 + 1;
  }
  else {
    idx++;
  }

  if (idx >= len) {
    return nil;
  }

  if (c_key[idx++] != 0x00) {
    return nil;
  }

  if (idx >= len) {
    return nil;
  }

  // Now make a new NSData from this buffer
  return([NSData dataWithBytes:&c_key[idx] length:len - idx]);
}

- (SecKeyRef)publicKey:(NSData *)d_key withTag:(NSString *)tag
{
  NSData *d_tag = [NSData dataWithBytes:[tag UTF8String] length:[tag length]];

  NSDictionary *saveDict = @{
                             (__bridge id) kSecClass : (__bridge id) kSecClassKey,
                             (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyType : (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                             (__bridge id) kSecAttrApplicationTag : d_tag,
                             (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClass : (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
                             (__bridge id) kSecValueData : d_key
                             };

  OSStatus secStatus = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)saveDict, NULL );
  if (secStatus == errSecDuplicateItem ) {
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)saveDict);
    secStatus = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)saveDict, NULL );
  }

  if ( secStatus != noErr ) {
    return NULL;
  }

  NSDictionary *queryDict = @{
                              (__bridge id) kSecClass : (__bridge id) kSecClassKey,
                              (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyType : (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                              (__bridge id) kSecAttrApplicationTag : tag,
                              (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClass : (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
                              (__bridge id) kSecReturnRef : (__bridge id) kCFBooleanTrue
                              };

  // Now fetch the SecKeyRef version of the key
  SecKeyRef keyRef = nil;
  secStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryDict,
                                  (CFTypeRef *)&keyRef);

  if ( secStatus != noErr ) {
    return NULL;
  }

  return keyRef;
}

NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"base64encoded X509 private key"
                                                              options:0];
certificateData = [self stripPublicKeyHeader2:keyData];
SecKeyRef key = [self publicKey:certificateData withTag:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
```

Little bit awkward, not my code, was Googling for the whole day, many pieces glued together. Have to clean it, ... Take it as a hack compiled from the internet.

Tested against server where code is in Java and this is the only way how to do it. The only way I did find. Maybe there are another ways, but only this one does work for me and I can encrypt with this RSA public key (and our server code (Java) can decrypt it. And it does work only without padding (not recommended) or with `kSecPaddingOAEP` padding on iOS side and with `RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding` on Java side.